# Unable to use Splits effectively in Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I searched unsuccessfully Screen's info manual in Emacs by C-s. I was not able to search all nodes at once.

I can create a split by

```
C-a S
```

in Screen, move between them by

```
C-a TAB
```

and close them by

```
C-a X
```

However, I cannot launch anything on them. I have now two same windows in two splits.

I want to start a new session in other split, similarly as in Vim by

```
:args newFile
```

**How can you start a new session in the second split?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C-a c` will create a new screen window in the current split.

You can also execute commands in screen by typing `C-a :` and then the command, then Enter. Then you could do something similar to what you're describing:

```
:screen vi look-a-new-screen-window-started-with-vi.txt
```

Also, since you might be used to Vim's window-movement keys, try binding the `C-a j` to moving to the next split down and `C-a k` to move to the previous split upward, just like Vim's `C-w j` and `C-w k`. In your `.screenrc`:

```
bind j focus down
bind k focus up
```

---

While I'm sharing screen stuff, here's a handy bit to add to your screenrc to give you a nice status bar at the bottom showing all of your screen windows with the current one highlighted:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{k}%-w%{.kY}%n %t%{-}%+w %= %H: %l %d/%m %c"
```

Rename a window with `C-a A`.

Comment: I am interested in you last hardstatus command. I get the following to my bottomBar: as-fe3dd00-8: 0.33 0.24 0.26 08/05 10:33. The first network. The next which I know is date and clock. What are the others?

Comment: On the right you should see your hostname; the load over the last 1, 5 and 15 minutes per the `uptime` command; and the date and time.

I'm not sure offhand how the initial color sequences work, but they're documented in the `screen` man page under "STRING ESCAPES".

Answer (score 2):

`C-a c` to create a new window (and immediately switch to that window)
`C-a w` to list windows
`C-a` and a window number to switch windows.

You can change default keybindings using a [screenrc](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/Screen/screenrc_examples.shtml) file, but I don't think you can bind multiple commands to a single keypress.

However, if there's a common set of screens that you're using you can get screen to start with these already open (and running whichever programs you want) by default. Check out the screenrc's on [dotfiles](http://dotfiles.org/.screenrc) for some great tips.

A simple ~/.screenrc for getting screen to automatically open a couple of sessions (with a split is as follows)

```
screen -t vim vim
split
focus down
startup_message off
screen -t home
```

Which will open two screen sessions with a split, the first named vim (running vim) and the second named home, just waiting with the normal shell prompt.

You can use different screenrc files with `screen -c nameOfYourScreenRC`, so if you wanted a different screenrc file to set up a vim session and a gdb session you could just do `screen -c gdbscreenrc` if you'd set up the appropriate file.

Comment: Your question raised a new question. How can you edit the C-a S to be C-a S C-a c?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! -- I get the following text at my Vim when I start terminal: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/vim.png. Do you know how I can get rid of it?